# How do I set the drush tmp directory?

Tags: drush

I understand how to use /etc/drush/drush.ini; however, I don't know what exactly to put in there in order for Drush to use a different temp directory when creating an archive-dump.

Answer (score 3):

You can change drush temp directory by seting the TEMP environment variable.

In linux:

```
export TEMP=/mnt/tmp
```

will instruct drush to store your temporary dump to /mnt/tmp.

Depends on operating system, it can be set with different variable.
For more details, the code is here: drush/includes/filesystem.inc: function drush_find_tmp()

https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/de8106ba13a286320fcced88f04fbe6ae119fd4b/includes/filesystem.inc#L436

Comment: Tried this and does not help the issue. Archive dump is still using /tmp even when I changed sys_temp_dir in my custom php.ini.

Answer (score 2):

```
$options['dump-dir'] = '/path/to/dumpdir';
```

found in example.drushrc.php :)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something.  As indicated, I copied the contents of example.drushrc.php into /etc/drush/drushrc.php; commented out the line for the temp directory, and still get this output when I perform a drush archive-dump: temp : /tmp

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify a bit.  I need to be able to have a drush archive-dump use a different directory than /tmp (which I think is set via an environment variable.)  My /tmp mount point is too small to handle a drush archive-dump; so the dump fails.

Comment: have you tried speciying the  --destination parameter ?

Comment: I did...however it still uses /tmp as a temporary storing place during the achive-dump process.

Comment: I can confirm that this does not solve the issue either. The temporary dump file is still stored in /tmp

Answer (score 1):

For Drush 7 sql-sync you can specify --target-dump

That specifies the actual file Drush will write to on the target.

```
$ drush sql-sync @site.prod @site.self --target-dump=/tmp/self/prod-db.sql.gz
```

NB This should answer " 
Perhaps I should clarify a bit. I need to be able to have a drush archive-dump use a different directory than /tmp (which I think is set via an environment variable.) My /tmp mount point is too small to handle a drush archive-dump; so the dump fails. – Mike Broyles Mar 13 '13 at 0:34", but I don't have reputation here so therefor a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Drush 6, see https://drupal.org/node/1806416. That patch may or may not get backported to Drush5. See that link for current status.