# Dump-dir specified in aliases.drushrc.php; not seen by drush?

Tags: drush

The remote and local directories I've specified in my aliases files exist and are owned by my user (drush is run under my user).

```
$aliases['dev'] = array(
 'parent' => '@parent',
 'site' => 'mysite',
 'env' => 'dev',
 //[user, host, ssh options, etc.]
 'path-aliases' => array(
    '%files' => 'sites/default/disk',
    '%dump-dir' => '/home/joe/drush-backups/mysite_dev',
    ),
);    

$aliases['local'] = array(
 'parent' => '@parent',
 'site' => 'mysite',
 //[root]
 'path-aliases' => array(
     '%files' => 'sites/default/files',
     '%dump-dir' => '/Users/joe/Sites/mysite/tmp',
    ),
);
```

Yet I get a warning on sql-sync:

> drush -v sql-sync @dev @local Loaded alias @local from file
>   /Users/joe/.drush/soa.aliases.drushrc.php
>   [notice] Loaded alias @dev from file
>   /Users/joe/.drush/soa.aliases.drushrc.php
>   [notice] Local sql cache file does not exist.
>   [notice] ssh -i "/Users/joe/.ssh/id_rsa" -p "6421"
>   joe@arch-web-p01.its.utexas.edu 'drush  --backend=2
>   --root=/var/www/html/dev  sql-query '\''SHOW TABLES'\'' 2>&1' 2>&1                                                                                                  [notice] WARNING:  Using temporary files to store and transfer
>   sql-dump.  It is recommended that you specify --source-dump and
>   --target-dump options on the command line, or set '%dump' or '%dump-dir' in the path-aliases section of your site alias records.
>   This facilitates fast file transfer via rsync.
>
> You will destroy data in drupal_test and replace with data from
>   server/mysite_dev.
>
> You might want to make a backup first, using the sql-dump command.

And if I continue, I get an error that indicates drush was trying to write to a different directory.

> Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y Calling system(ssh -i
>   "/Users/joe/.ssh/id_rsa" -p "6421" joe@server 'mysqldump --result-file
>   /private/var/folders/mr/c99kf6c11_bdsr62m242c59c0000gq/T/mysite_dev1WyWuk
>   --no-autocommit --single-transaction --opt -Q  mysite_dev --host=myhost --user=mysite_dev --password='\''[pw]'\'' --skip-extended-insert --order-by-primary  2>&1'); mysqldump: Can't create/write to file
>   '/private/var/folders/mr/c99kf6c11_bdsr62m242c59c0000gq/T/mysite_dev1WyWuk'
>   (Errcode: 2) Database dump failed
>   [error] Command dispatch complete
>   [notice]

I've got all my drush commands working between remote directories run on the site. I am able to rsync between local and remote directories since specifying files path aliases in aliases.drushrc.php.

What am I missing?  I have the latest version of drush in both places, so I don't think I need the patch pointed to at [How do I set the drush tmp directory?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65271/how-do-i-set-the-drush-tmp-directory)...

Comment: I did not try to reproduce your issue, but I think this might be a recent issue in Drush, possibly a duplicate of https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/321. If you are using 6.2.0, try on 6.0.0. In any event, what you are doing above looks correct.

Comment: Hmm. So actually I'm using 6.0-rc2, installed with brew.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FWIW, I finally resolved the error by including the --source-dump option in the command line. I specified the same directory I had listed in my aliases file, and it created the dump file there flawlessly. So perhaps dump-dir is not being read in 6.0-rc2...

Comment: I still see the same problem in Drush 8.1.2.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the same error. When you specify `%dump-dir`, you also must specify the `%dump` variable, then it works:

```
'path-aliases' => array(
  '%dump-dir' => '/home/tmp',
  '%dump' => '/home/tmp/dump.sql',
),
```

Comment: made no difference on drush 8.1.9

Answer (score 0):

`dump-dir` and `dump` options were remove somewhere in version `7.x` https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/commit/df3980062a89436a26db20097363da69616cbb9c

You can still find it in `6.x` branch but not in `8.x`
https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/6.x/examples/example.aliases.drushrc.php

In issue https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/1495 you can read:

> markcarver: What happened to drush_sql_dump_file()?
>
> weitzman: The feature is gone. sql-sync does not keep around transferred dump
> files any more.